# Windows Phone Mango: Making a drawing app with various brushes option

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, drawing, paint

I am trying to make a drawing app. The purpose is simple. Let the user draw something on a canvas with various brush options like **square brush,far brush,pencil brush** and many more like any other drawing app available in android market. At present I can let the user draw smooth curves using following code:

```
                currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this.canvas);
                Line line = new Line() { X1 = currentPoint.X, Y1 = currentPoint.Y, X2 = oldPoint.X, Y2 = oldPoint.Y };
                line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple);
                line.StrokeThickness = 2;
                this.drawnImage.Add(line);
                this.canvas.Children.Add(line);
                oldPoint = currentPoint;
```

Now I want some custom brush options and let the user draw using that.How can I achieve that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Square, Pencil etc are merely custom image pattern used as brush. Go with [ImageBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)